# RDLC datatype for list

Tags: c#, reporting-services, dataset, rdlc

I am very new in RDLC report. i need to display the list inside my report.
Here is the class that I want to display all the objects in my report

```
public class Product
{
   public string ProductPictureURL { get; set; } 
   public List<TechnicalData> TechnicalData { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class TechnicalData
{
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this dataset in my .rdlc report

```
<DataSet Name="ProductDataSet">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>MyModel</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText />
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="ProductPictureURL">
          <DataField>ProductPictureURL</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="TechnicalData">
          <DataField>TechnicalData</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>???</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
  </DataSet>
```

The question is how I should put <rd:TypeName> of type List in my rdlc (in this case List TechnicalData)?

OR

What is the best way to display the list in RDLC report?

Comment: See following : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473844/Using-Custom-Data-Source-to-create-RDLC-Reports

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks :)